# Can two networks have the same address with different masks?

Tags: routing, ipv4, subnet

Is it possible for two networks to have the same network IP address if two different masks are used?

Take for instance the addresses `200.23.18.0/24` and `200.23.18.0/27`. I'm thinking that this might be problematic. Suppose a router that connects the two networks recieves a datagram whose destiny is, for example, `200.23.18.3`... How can it know where to send it? What path would the datagram follow? AFAIK, the host could be located in any of the two networks described above, so I don't see a solution if this is allowed to happen.

Comment: If it wasn't clear from the answer, having overlapping addresses is (with very few exceptions) an invalid addressing scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be overlapping routes which will cause connectivity issues.

Usually a router will pick the destination with the highest bit matching precedence, in other words the route with the longest mask.

[image]

Comment: How come the destination has a "higher bit matching" with just one of the networks? I don't get that, as the destination IP could be in any of them.

Comment: Let us ignore the first 3 bytes as they are constants and covered by both masks. Mask 24 has then nothing more to match (24 bits = all 3 first bytes), whereas mask 27 has still 3 bits to match. IP address 200.23.18.3, and for our discussion in fact its latest byte with value 3 matches the 200.23.18.0/27 mask as in both cases, vales 0 and 3 of the last byte, share their first 3 bits (000). So IP 200.23.18.3 matches 200.23.18.3/27 "more" than 200.23.18.3/24.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: We should also point out that while a router can route into and out of 200.23.18.0/24 and 200.23.18.0/27 by themselves, *you can't route between them*, i.e. from /24 to /27 because the /27 adresses appear to be local to /24 and no gateway is used (unless you work with static ARP entries, proxy ARP or even more quirks).